# What is the true space-complexity of saving all divisors, because $N$ can have more divisors than the length of $N$?

Tags: space-complexity, factoring

$6983776800$ in binary has 33 bits but has $2034$ positive divisors.

If a list of divisors were to be logarithmic in N, it needs to take less than 33 bits.

I believe there is an infinite amount of numbers with more divisors than the bits used to represent them.

Thus it is not possible for any algorithm to create a list using log-space.

So given the worst case, that $N$ has a vast amount of divisors what is the true space-complexity?

Answer (score 4):

“Saving all divisors” is just not a clever way to go about it. It’s much better to factor N into the product of powers of distinct primes, which has about the same size as N, and all divisors can be enumerated from that easily.

But then, if N has n bits, it can be the product of about n/log n primes of log n bits each, so there are about 2^(n / log n) possible products of n/2 bits each on average. So the logarithm of the size of all factors is about n/log n. I’m sure you can do this a bit more precise.

Comment: If we want to store factorisations for all integers up to some maximum, a compact way is to store just the smallest prime factor $p[i]$ for each $i$. The complete set of prime factors can then be recovered for any $i$: it's $p[i]$, plus the result of recursing on $i/p[i]$.